# Bash prompt on Ubuntu - FQDN (\H) same as hostname (\h)

Tags: ubuntu, bash, fqdn

We've got seperate environments at my workplace for development, testing, integration, and staging.

Within those envs, we've overloaded the hostnames in DNS - e.g. in the dev environment, the primary web machine is called `web1.dev.example.com`, and in the test environment, the primary web machine is `web1.test.example.com`.

To distinguish between machines in the different environments, I want to customise the bash prompts to display the FQDN rather than just the hostname. Well and good; I should be able to replace `\h` with `\H` in `$PS1`, right? Hmm. They show the exact same thing.

```
me@web1:~$ hostname
web1
me@web1:~$ hostname -f
web1.dev.example.com
me@web1:~$ export PS1="\[\u@\h: \w\]\$ "
me@web1: ~$ export PS1="\[\u@\H: \w\]\$ "
me@web1: ~$
```

In `/etc/hostname`, I've got *just* the hostname (`web1`). `hostname` and `hostname -f` both return the correct results ("web1" and "web1.test.example.com" respectively), and I've got the correct entries in `/etc/hosts`.

What gives?

These are Ubuntu 10.04 hosts, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try using an explicit call to `hostname -f` to get the fqdn of the system

```
export PS1="\[\u@$(hostname -f): \w\]\$ "
```

e.g.

```
iain$ export PS1="\[\u@$(hostname -f): \w\]\$ "
iain@ub10-04-1.lan: ~$
```

EDIT:

Further research shows that the contents of `/etc/hostname` (Ubuntu) and `/etc/sysconfig/network` (CentOS) are relevant. If the FQDN is in the file then the `\H` works correctly.

The hostname(1) man page for Ubuntu does though say that you shouldn't put the FQDN in /etc/hostname but gives no reason as to why.

Comment: That's kinda ugly :( But it does work. I might leave this open for a bit longer, it'd be really nice to have a "clean" fix.

Comment: This appears to be related to debian/ubuntu. It works as expected in centos.

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely a Ubuntu problem. I've ended up using your suggested solution; I should really report this as a bug against Bash in Ubuntu.

Comment: @BenWilliams: updated answer with what should make it less fugly.

Comment: I've also found that same ambiguity in Ubuntu's hostname-setting docs. Not sure how to resolve it.

Answer (score 5):

There is an insane amount of craziness about hostnames, short and long, and getting it right all the time is *hard* -- so I just give up and make everything use the FQDN as the hostname...

I do the same thing as you in my environments, but I chop down the FQDNs in the prompt because I *know* what site I'm on, and it saves space.  I also colour-code my prompt based on environment so I've got a better warning of when I'm doing something somewhere "important".  I also space-separate the path from everything else, to make it easy to copy-pasta pwd.  A snippet from my stock `/etc/profile`:

```
if hostname -f | grep -q '\.stg\.example\.com'; then
  _ROOT_COLOR=33  # yellow
  _USER_COLOR=36  # cyan
else
  _ROOT_COLOR=31  # red
  _USER_COLOR=32  # green
fi

if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
  PS1="\[\033[01;${_ROOT_COLOR}m\]$(hostname -f|sed 's/\.example\.com//')\[\033[01;34m\] \w #\[\033[00m\] "
else
  PS1="\[\033[01;${_USER_COLOR}m\]\u@$(hostname -f|sed 's/\.example\.com//')\[\033[01;34m\] \w $\[\033[00m\] "
fi
```

And, as far as "ugliness" goes, who cares what the code to display the prompt looks like?  It's write-only code most of the time, anyway.

Comment: +1 for the color usage.

Answer (score 0):

That is a bug with how Ubuntu manages /etc/hostname.

Bug filed:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bash/+bug/1276796