# Amazon Cloud Instance SSH prompt customization

Tags: bash, ssh, amazon-ec2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bash prompt on Ubuntu - FQDN (\H) same as hostname (\h)](https://serverfault.com/questions/296970/bash-prompt-on-ubuntu-fqdn-h-same-as-hostname-h)

Is it possible to customize ssh shell prompt to show domain name instead of ip e.g

```
ubuntu@ip-xx-xxx-xx-xxx:~$
```

with

```
ubuntu@dev.mydomain.com:~$
```

Edit: I do not want to hard code the domain name instead I want to fetch the associated domain name

Answer (score 2):

The shell prompt is decided by the `PS1` variable in bash. My current `PS1` is :

```
[ec2-user@phinfinity.com ~]$ echo $PS1
[\u@\H \W]\$
```

the parameter `\H` specifies to place the hostname. you can replace your bashrc to use something like 
    export PS1="\u@dev.mydomain.com:\W$"

A better option should be to change your hostname to `dev.mydomain.com` . Check the man page of the `hostname` command to setup your hostname in linux.

Check : 
[Linux Hostname Configuration](http://jblevins.org/log/hostname)

Comment: thanks, is it possible to retrieve domain name associated with the Amazon ec2 instance directly through some command ? So this can be done with all amazon instances